# JMeter - Measure Page Load time with AJAX

Tags: jmeter

My Page has multiple portlet. Each portlet displays data asynchronously using AJAX. Can JMeter help me here. There are many posts in internet which doesn't clearly state if this is possible or not.

I read an interesting post where someone suggested that AJAX requests can be captured and total time can be derived by using a Transaction controller. But at other side someone mentions AJAX requests can never be captured.

So would like to check here and see if any of JMeter gurus can shed light on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a JMeter Guru! But i can understand the issue you are facing now.

AJAX requests are HTTP requests & so it can be captured with JMeter. (I know I have done). As they say Transaction controller will give the total time of the transaction . ie - If you place 4 http requests / AJAX requests under a transaction controller - it will give you the total time of all those 4 requests.

But the issue is - JMeter will call these AJAX/HTTP requests sequentially. But, your browser might make these calls in parallel (depends on your application). In that case - The time you get with JMeter might NOT be correct.

**JMeter is not a correct tool to measure Browser's page load time. If you are not aware - it does not execute any javascript. But your browser does. So actual browser page load time might be different.**

Answer (score 0):

The parallel request issue can be easily dealt with though.
You can use a thread group in jmeter which has as many parallel threads as your browser has parallel requests.

Therefore, though it is surely not an accurate measurement of the time a browser would need, I can see a few applications for this approach.

If the browser loading pattern is modelled closely enough we should be able to collect some useful results which closely correlate to the timing figures we are looking for.